# Django: How to return with context from UpdateView (CBV)?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

The following view works as expected

```
class BrandEditView(PermissionRequiredMixin ,generic.UpdateView):
    permission_required = 'change_brand'

    template_name = 'brand_update_form.pug'
    model = Brand
    fields = ['name']

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        print(self.request.user)
        self.object = Brand.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        obj = Brand.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return obj
```

After form submission, how do I return to the same view (with the same object), but with context, like a message: "brand edited successfully"/"you can't do that"? I've found a way to redirect to the same view, but not with context.

Answer (score 1):

to use the message framework in class based view we use the SuccessMessageMixin

so update your view to be like this:

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
class BrandEditView(SuccessMessageMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin ,generic.UpdateView):
    permission_required = 'change_brand'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('your redirect url')
    template_name = 'brand_update_form.pug'
    model = Brand
    fields = ['name']
    success_message = "created successfully!"
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        print(self.request.user)
        self.object = Brand.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        obj = Brand.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return obj
```

and in the base template or any template add this:

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>
        {{ message }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```